# Moving ECDSA from COM DLL to .NET

Tags: vb.net, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I have an ActiveX DLL that uses ECDSACom from Dragongate Technologies to create a signature for a product license. The product, when starting, uses the signature generated, the public key and the license to check if the license is good.

But now I'm changing to .NET and 64bit applications and the ECDSACom can't be used since is a COM DLL. Is there any library so I can check the signature (given the signature, data that was signed and public key)?

Answer (score 0):

[sweep of old questions]

http://clrsecurity.codeplex.com/ and if that's not working, try Bouncy Castle.